# "Normal" variables in Upstart

Tags: upstart

I haven't quite figured out, how to use "normal" bash variables in an Upstart script.

Basically, I just want to do this.

```
DAEMON="/usr/bin/redis-server"
DAEMON_ARGS="/etc/redis/redis.conf"
RUNDIR="/var/run/redis"
PIDFILE="$RUNDIR/redis-server.pid"

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /media/redis/
    mkdir -p /var/log/redis/
    mkdir -p $RUNDIR
    touch $PIDFILE
    chown redis:redis $RUNDIR $PIDFILE
    chmod 755 $RUNDIR
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
    echo $DAEMON
    exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid redis:redis --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
end script
```

But, of course, this doesn't work. Prefixing the variable declarations with `env` kinda works, but doesn't allow for interpolation.

```
# using `env` the variables are accessible in the entire file.
env DAEMON="/usr/bin/redis-server"
env DAEMON_ARGS="/etc/redis/redis.conf"
env RUNDIR="/var/run/redis"
env PIDFILE="$RUNDIR/redis-server.pid"
# however interpolation doesn't work
# `echo $PIDFILE` -> $RUNDIR/redis-server.pid
```

If I move the variable declaration inside a block (like `pre-start` or `script`), they work, but only inside that block. If I define them in the `pre-start` block, they are undefined in the main block.

There has to be a sane way of doing this.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "env kinda works" and what you mean by interpolation ?

Comment: @thom Added an example.

Comment: Did you try this?: RUNDIR="/var/run/redis" ; PIDFILE="$RUNDIR/redis-server.pid" ; env RUNDIR ; env PIDFILE

Comment: Or replace "env" with "export" ?